# Tuning subquery in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have discovered some suspect data in a database. I am attempting to determine if a certain field, lastname, is correct. I have come up with the following query in postgres:

```
SELECT members."memberID", 
       members.lastname 
  FROM members 
 WHERE members."memberID" NOT IN (SELECT members."memberID" 
                                    FROM members 
                                   WHERE members.lastname ~* '[a-zA-z]+([-][a-zA-Z]+)*');
```

The subquery currently matches against normal names and names with a hypen. The parent query should display the members who don't match that pattern. Currently the query takes an incredible amount of time to run (i've never seen it complete). I am not sure why it takes so long or how to improve it.

Comment: @OMG What happened to my edit?

Comment: @OMG: actually... ignore. I'm being daft :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like OMG Ponies answer, but *if* `memberID` is unique (i.e., PK), you can just drop the subquery altogether.

```
SELECT members."memberID", 
       members.lastname 
  FROM members 
 WHERE members.lastname !~ '[a-zA-Z]+([-][a-zA-Z]+)*';
```

(I deleted the case-insensitive operator since the regexp covers both cases.)

Answer (score 3):

### NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT m."memberID", 
       m.lastname 
  FROM MEMBERS m 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM MEMBERS b
                    WHERE b.lastname ~* '[a-zA-z]+([-][a-zA-Z]+)*'
                      AND b."memberID" = m."memberID");
```

### LEFT JOIN / IS NULL

```
   SELECT m."memberID", 
          m.lastname 
     FROM MEMBERS m 
LEFT JOIN MEMBERS b ON b."memberID" = m."memberID"
                   AND b.lastname ~* '[a-zA-z]+([-][a-zA-Z]+)*'
    WHERE b."memberID" IS NULL
```

### Summary

[Quote](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/):

> PostgreSQL treats `LEFT JOIN` and `NOT EXISTS` equally, using same execution plan for both of them (namely a Hash Anti Join for the example above).
>
> As for `NOT IN`, which is semantically different since its logic is trivalent and it can return NULL, PostgreSQL tries to take this into account and limits itself to using a filter against a subplan (a hashed subplan for a hashable resultset like in example above).
>
> Since it need to search the hash table for each missing value twice (first time to find the value, second time to find a NULL), this method is a little less efficient.
>
> A plain subplan, which the optimizer can resort to any time it decides the list will not fit into the memory, is very inefficient and the queries that have possibility of using it should be avoided like a plague.
>
> That’s why in PostgreSQL 8.4 one should always use `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` or `NOT EXISTS` rather than `NOT IN` to find the missing values.

#### Addendum

But as Andrew Lazarus points out, if there are no duplicates of memberid in the `MEMBERS` table, the query only needs to be:

```
SELECT m."memberID", 
       m.lastname 
  FROM MEMBERS m 
 WHERE b.lastname ~* '[a-zA-z]+([-][a-zA-Z]+)*'
```

Comment: Think there is a typo in the `NOT EXISTS` version. `WHERE NOT EXISTS ...` not `WHERE m.memberId NOT EXISTS ...`.